# How to initialise a KO observable from the server

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

If I have an HTML element that is pre-populated from the server (e.g. PHP or ASP.NET) like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:TheMeaningOfLife" data-revert-to="42" />
```

and I declare my model as

```
var TheMeaningOfLife = ko.observable(69);
```

how can I get the model to initialise with the value of data-revert-to? I started with the following custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serverValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccesor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var el = $(element);
        var serverValue = el.data("revert-to");
        if (serverValue == undefined) {
            return;
        }

        el.val(serverValue);
    }
}
```

and update my control to

```
<input type="text" data-bind="serverValue:TheMeaningOfLife" data-revert-to="42" />
```

but that seems to kill the update event, because when I change the value in the textbox, the viewmodel does not update.

**Solution as per segfault's answer**

I tweaked segfault's answer a little to follow more closely how the server code is emitted:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serverValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccesor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var observable = valueAccesor();
        if (observable() == undefined) {
            var el = $(element);
            var serverValue = el.data("revert-to");
            observable(serverValue);
        }

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: observable });
    }
}
```

and this works just fine. I just need to make sure that the observable is initialised with a null, rather than an empty string.

Comment: Have you tried where `TheMeaningOfLife` is a property on _another_ object?  I'm not sure it's binding correctly to your observable at all here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never check the observable so you are always using the revert to value. If you do a check on the value accesor and if its provided dont overwrite it.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="serverValue:TheMeaningOfLife, defaultValue='42'" />

ko.bindingHandlers.serverValue = {
            init: function (element, valueAccesor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                var myValue = null;
                var observable = valueAccesor();
                if (observable() == undefined) {
                    observable(allBindingsAccessor.defaultValue);
                }
                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: observable });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the job for me! I've updated the question above to show the (slightly reworked) solution. Many many thanks, I was bashing my head against the wall on this one.